# How to set Module 'In Use' in DNN Installation.?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-6

I have successfully Installed packages of Flex Event, I am learning DNN. 
Now I don't Know how to use and Further Process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As soon as a module is dropped on any page in the site the system will automatically flag it as "In Use."

That column is designed to help users understand which modules might be used, versus, modules installed but no longer or not yet implemented.

Comment: Can I Edit this flag.?

Comment: No, and why would you? It's just as Mitchel Sellers writes. If you want it to say "Yes" just add the module to a page in any portal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can I Know how to run this module?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question entirely, but you can run this module since it has been installed. If it were the incorrect DNN version it would say so during module installation.

Comment: I have used DNN 7.3.3 and Flex Events 2.0.4 package.